# Let $f(x)=x^4+2x^2-x-1$ . Calculate an upper limit and a lower limit of the real roots, and a lower limit of the positive roots.

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

Let $f(x)=x^4+2x^2-x-1$. Calculate $(i)$ an upper limit and $(ii)$ a lower limit of the real roots of $f$ and $(iii)$ a lower limit of the positive roots of $f.$

The definitions given to me are as follows :

> Let the equation $f(x)=0$ be written with the coefficient of the leading
> term positive. A real number $u$ is an upper limit of the real roots of the equation
> $f(x)=0$ if $f(x)>0$ for all $x\geq u$. A real number $l$ is a lower limit of the real roots of the equation
> $f(x)=0$ if it is an upper limit of the equation $f(-x)=0$. A real number $h$ is said to be a lower limit of the positive roots of $f(x)=0$, if $\frac{1}{h}$ is an upper limit of the positive roots of $f(\frac{1}{x})=0$ .

The solution is as follows:

> Let $f(x) = x^4+2x^2-x-1$.Then $f(x)>0$ if $x\geq 1$. Therefore $1$ is an upper limit of the real roots.$f(-x)=x^4+2x^2+x-1$. So, $1$ is an upper limit of the real roots of $f(-x)=0$.Therefore $-1$ is a lower limit of the real roots of the equation $f(x)=0$.
> $f(\frac{1}{x})=0$ gives $x^4+x^3-2x^2-1 =0$. $2$ is an upper limit of the positive roots of the equation $f(\frac{1}{x})=0$. Therefore $\frac{1}{2}$ is a lower limit of the positive roots of $f(x)=0$.

In the equation $f(-x)=0$ , if we assume $y=-x$,  then we have $f(y)=0$  and upper limit of $f(y)$ is $1$. Now, $y=-x$ and hence, $x=-1$ . So, $-1$ is the upper limit of $f(-x)=0$ and from the definitions above we can say $-1$ is the the lower limit of $f(x)=0$. Is my understanding correct?

In the part $iii$ of the problem we can proceed in a similar way as well. If we consider $y=\frac{1}{x}$, then $f(y)=0$ has an upper limit $1$. However, $2$ can also be an upper limit as $2>1$ . So, if $y=2$ then $y=\frac{1}{x}=2$. Thus, $x=1/2$. Hence, from the definition above $y=1/h=2$ is the upper limit of $f(y)=f(\frac{1}{x}=0$,so ,$h=2$ is the lower limit of the positive real roots of $f(x)=0$. Is my understanding from part $iii$ correct?

EDIT: I still haven't quite found an acceptable answer or rather my questions are still unanswered .

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141331/discussion-on-question-by-arthur-let-fxx42x2-x-1-calculate-an-upper-li).

Answer (score -1):

(Example of) a **proof of "$f(x)>0$ if $x\ge1$":** If $x\ge1$ then $x^4\ge x$ and $2x^2>1,$ hence $x^4+2x^2-x-1>x+1-x-1=0.$

**Explanations of the solution for (ii):**

1. the definition "lower limit of the roots of $f(x)=0$ = upper limit of the roots of $f(-x)=0$" was weird and *the solution relies on a different definition.*
   The intended meaning of "$v$ is a lower limit of the roots of $f(x)=0$" is:
   $v$ is a *strict lower bound* of the set of roots, i.e.
    $\forall x\le v\quad f(x)\ne0,$ which is equivalent to
   $\forall y\ge -v\quad f(-y)\ne0,$ i.e.
   $\forall x\ge -v\quad f(-x)\ne0,$ i.e.
   the *opposite* of $v$ is an upper limit of the roots of $f(-x)=0.$
   This explains why they say "$1$ is an upper limit of the real roots of $f(-x)=0$. *Therefore* $-1$ is a lower limit of the real roots of the equation $f(x)=0$."
2. Now, the initial claim ("$1$ is an upper limit of the real roots of $f(-x)=0$"), i.e. $\forall x\ge1\quad x^4+2x^2+x-1>0,$ can be proved the same way (even more easily) as the analogous previous claim in (i).

**Explanations of the solution for (iii):**

1. Here also, the definition should be corrected. The intended meaning of "$h$ is a lower limit of the positive roots of $f(x)=0$" is: "$h$ is a strict lower bound of $\{x>0\mid f(x)=0\}.$" As noticed by Hagen von Eitzen, any $h\le0$ would then be a correct answer. But if one chooses the slight variation of your book (reducing to: "an upper limit of the roots of $f(1/x)=0$" - *the word "positive" before "roots" is meaningless here*), one has to *restrict to positive $h$'s*, because if $h<0$ that definition corresponds to a property which is not at all what is intended.
2. Anyway, that makes no difference here since they chose $h=\frac12,$ which is $>0.$ Let us analyze step by step their solution.
   * "$f(1/x)=0$ gives $x^4+x^3-2x^2-1 =0$" because $f(1/x)=(1+2x^2-x^3-x^4)/x^4$ and they rewrite the equation "[as a polynomial equation] with the coefficient of the leading term positive".
   * "$2$ is an upper limit of the <s>positive</s> roots of the equation $f(1/x)=0$" because $\forall x\ge2\quad x^4+x^3-2x^2-1>0.$ (E.g. because if $x\ge2$ then $x^4>2x^2$ and $x^3>1$.)
   * *Therefore* $\frac12$ is a "lower limit of the positive roots of $f(x)=0$": by definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer makes it much clearer ...However, I want to verify a thing about part $ii$: so , $v$ is a lower limit of roots of $f(x)$ if $v$ is a strict lower bound for the set of roots of $f(x)$ i.e $\forall x\leq v$, $f(x)\neq 0$.  Now,  if $x\leq v$ , then $-x\geq -v$ , $f(x)\neq 0$. So, $\forall -x\geq -v$, $f(x)\neq 0$. If $y=-x$, then $y\geq -v$, $f(-y)\neq 0$. We can represent this condition as $\forall x\geq -v$, we have ,$f(-x)\neq 0$. This is how you arrived at this conclusion , right? Next, since, this conclusion holds true , we can say that $-v$ is an upper

Comment: limit of the equation $f(-x)=0$. But I want to know why my explanation of part $ii$ was not valid by change of variables ? I understand your solution for part $iii$ but if you provide a justification about the slight variation of the definition of the lower limit of the positive roots which was intended in the above solution of the original post . I did not get it how the definition given for lower limit of positive roots remain valid ?...

Comment: I think the definition used in the original solution I posted remains valid because: if $v$ is the upper limit of $f(1/x)=0$, then $\forall x\geq v$ ,$f(1/x)\neq 0$. Now, $x\geq v $ implies $1/x\leq 1/v$. Thus, $\forall 1/x\leq 1/v$, $f(1/x)\neq 0$. If $y=1/x$ then the former statement is equivalent to $\forall y\leq 1/v$, $f(y)\neq 0$. Thus, $\forall x\leq 1/v$ , $f(x)\neq 0$. This statement thus imples , $1/v$ is a lower limit of $f(x)$ and hence the definition given remains valid, right?...

Comment: @Anne Bauval That's actually a good point what Arthur wrote and this might need a little bit clarity ...infact, if I am not mistaken then the understanding part in the original part might well be correct...though cant deny the definitions are written in a weird manner...

Comment: @Arthur Энн Бьюваль не ответит на ваш вопрос, я думаю

Comment: Well @Franklin you *are* mistaken. I think I gave enough explanations and they at least don't deserve such a downvote. In particular, Arthur's last comment here is incorrect.  Find the flaw... ;-) (the hint is contained in my explanations).

Comment: Почему? Я дал полный контекст, я думаю...

Comment: @AnneBauval But are the previous two comments correct?...

Comment: I was discouraged by this endless dialogue so I didn't read. But wait. Well the 1st one is a copy-paste of my explanation for (ii), so yes. The 2nd one is neither correct nor incorrect, it is just an expression of dismay. I did my best, I cannot do more.

Comment: @AnneBauval If I understand the OP correctly:he is just asking whether his understanding for $ii$ and $iii$ in his orginal post is correct or not ...

Comment: @Arthur You should make comments a little more concise and compact ...

Comment: @Franklin I already explained in length and width why it was not.

Comment: @AnneBauval You have already done more than enough for this case ...and I admit your answer ,answers most of it but I really don't see the validity of the definition of lower limit of positive roots written in my book ? So that was my question ....